# How to create a mongoDB view to get all records from the past n days?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to create a MongoDB view which will give me only last 2 days worth of records. I have created an aggregation pipeline with a $match aggregation.

It looks something like this:

```
[
     { $unwind:"$User" },
     { $unwind:"$User.Transaction" },
     { $match :{
         "User.Transaction.CreateDateUtc" : { $gte : new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()- 2))}}
     }
]
```

With the above piece of code, my view gets created but it doesn't take the current date when I query the view. Instead it takes the date when my view is created. $match stage looks like this in shell:

```
 { 
     "User.Transaction.CreateDateUtc" : { 
          "$gte" : ISODate("2019-08-29T10:01:17.610+0000") 
     } 
 }
```

So it doesn't show the last two days but for all the days since the view was created.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for using Studio 3T!

To answer your question, pipelines are only available in MongoDB 4.2.  We recommend updating to that to access the feature.